# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable To System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TiendaDeportes.producto>

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a property

```
public IEnumerable<producto> p_producto { 
    get { 
        return ((from ii in contexto.productos
                 orderby ii.nombre ascending
                 select new producto {
                               productoID = ii.productoId, 
                               nombre = ii.nombre,
                               descripcion = ii.descripcion, 
                               categoria = ii.categoria,
                               precio = ii.precio}));
        }
}
```

inside the Default.aspx

```
public IEnumerable<producto> filtroCategoria()
{
    IEnumerable<producto> productos = repositorio.p_producto; <---- Error why ?

}
```

Summary

> Cannot implicitly convert type
>   '`System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TiendaDeportes.Modelos.producto>`'
>   to '`System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TiendaDeportes.producto>`'.
>   An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two classes named `producto`. One within `TiendaDeportes` namespace and another in `TiendaDeported.Modelos`. Your repository returns `IEnumerable<T>` of the first one, and you're property in`Default.aspx` returns `IEnumerable<T>` of the second one. It cannot work.

Either change your property inside `Default.aspx` to return `IEnumerable<TiendaDeported.Modelos.producto>` or make additional `Select` call to map `TiendaDeported.Modelos.producto` to `TiendaDeported.producto`.

Comment: Thanks you very much my friend. Greetings from mexico